# Display images asynchronously in listfield blackberry

Tags: blackberry, listfield

While loading images from url in every row of a listfield,default image should be display until image is fetched. Then fetched image should be displayed. How to do this? please help.
I was trying following code but failed

```
 if(HttpUtils.getBitmap(url1)==null)
       {
           final Bitmap b1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("images.jpg");
           g.drawBitmap(0, y+5, b1.getWidth(),b1.getHeight(),b1, 0, 0);    
       }
```

Comment: Add the `default_bitmap_image` in a `BitmapField` then add the `BitmapField` to your `Manager` / `MainScreen`, then make request with your `image_url` for the Image, catch the response of the request, if successful and valid image-response is received then `.setBitmap(new_image)` the new image to your `BitmapField`, and finally call **`invalidate()`** to show the effect of the image-change.